# How to show video with transparent background?

Tags: android, transparency

My current task is to show an object in motion over a standard desktop. If it was static I'd better use a PNG image format with transparent background. But what to do if an object must move over icons and widgets? 
And the thing is that an object should be realistic (not like in cartoons). Several frames with transparency don't match either.

Comment: Could you describe your question a bit better?  What do you mean, a standard desktop?

Comment: I mean standard screen which people see after pressing Home button. For example, main HTC Sense tab with icons, widgets and wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation on [how to create a live wallpaper](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html) and review the [live wallpaper sample in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html).

As far as I know, there is no way to overlay things on the home screen, unless you're using a custom widget like you can use in Android 3.x.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to show object over icons, not behind them.

Comment: This is not possible unless you're controlling the entire homescreen, which you would have to distribute your own version of Android to do.